# Java If statement logic

Tags: arrays, if-statement, string-comparison

```
    System.out.println("Enter the answers pressing enter after every input : ");
    for(int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
        do {
            studentAnswers[x] = keyboard.next().toUpperCase();
            System.out.println(studentAnswers[x]);
            if (!"A".equals(studentAnswers[x]) || !"B".equals(studentAnswers[x]) ||
                !"C".equals(studentAnswers[x]) || !"D".equals(studentAnswers[x]))
                System.out.println("You entered an invalid input.");
        } while(!"A".equals(studentAnswers[x]) || !"B".equals(studentAnswers[x]) ||
                !"C".equals(studentAnswers[x]) || !"D".equals(studentAnswers[x]));
    }
```

Above is my code. For whatever reason, the condition for both the if statement and do-while loop are not recognizing the correct inputs. For example, if I input a, it will print "You entered an invalid input." I even had my teacher look at this. Unfortunately, he could not find an answer either. The array studentAnswers is a String, and I even have the line below the input to ensure that the input is being stored correctly.

I would appreciate any help in solving this problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should replace || with && as you need all the conditions to be true to determine the input is invalid. With || only one condition is needed and it always will be true by your condition statement.

Comment: Worth to mention that "a".equals("A") is false

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I'm disappointed I didn't notice that after a good hour of staring at my code. However, there is one thing I'd like to point out.

`if(!"A".equals(studentAnswers[x])`

When I was still in the troubleshooting stage, I changed my if statement to this only. It still wasn't working when I changed it to this alone. Why is that? There shouldn't have been an issue with logical operators.

Comment: @RedOne Impossible to say without knowing what the exact data used was. Could have been a mis-type for all we know.

Comment: @RedOne Why don't you try reproducing that bug for curiosity's sake?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzlurahyqQgscjNjdDN2alhFRWM/view?usp=sharing

Here's a link. This is a version of the code right when I started.

Comment: @RedOne You can't do `studentAnswers[x] != "A"` as a string in Java is a pointer, You have to do `!studentAnswers[x].equals("A")` as you have correctly done in the question. That's because this code didn't work either.

Comment: @DavidRojo Actually, I did that as well. It didn't work then, too. In fact, in the version of the program when I asked for help, that is how I initially had it.